# Why this Integer Addition crash on some devices?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I have the following function that works on Simulator and all my Devices but crashes on random devices where the app is running. What could be going wrong here? The crash report points to the line I have commented below. Thanks for your time and help.

```
func myTestFunction(date:NSDate)->Int{
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
formatter.dateFormat = "HH"
let hour = Int(formatter.string(from: date as Date))
formatter.dateFormat = "mm"
let minutes = Int(formatter.string(from: date as Date))
let tMinutes = (hour! * 60) + minutes! //Crash Here
return tMinutes
}
```

Comment: Have used a check for nil before force unwrapping. the answers by Mohammad Sadiq and @mildly-perilous helped me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You are force unwrapping `hour` and `minutes`. That is most probably the cause of the crash.

Comment: ok but can't understand why does it crash always on particular devices and never crash on others. can you suggest a solution? thanks

Comment: Before unwrapping use if let or guard let

Comment: let hour = Int(formatter.string(from: date as Date)) //  hour here is an optional value.  ie it might be nil if the date formatter is unsuccessful   Minutes is also optional.  let tMinutes = (hour! * 60) + minutes! //the ! is force unwrapping as said in the answer.  This means your telling the compiler you know for certain this will work so when you do get nil it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
let date = `your date here`
let calendar = Calendar.current
let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
let total_minutes = (hour*60)+minutes
```